# The map in bottom half and the top half of your screen is blank in Google Maps v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am using Google Maps v2 as a mapview in fragment in my application.
But it showing blank screen on top and bottom of screen as in the screenshot attached.

Please help me how to overcome this issue.

[image]

Following is the layout

```
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/resourceMapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/resourceScreenMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and following is the code used for it :

```
    mMpVwInstance = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.resourceScreenMapView);
    mMpVwInstance.onCreate(mBundle);
    mGglMapinstance = mMpVwInstance.getMap();
    mGglMapinstance.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mGglMapinstance.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

Comment: can you post your code...

Comment: ekjyot, did any of the below answers assist you? If so, please consider voting on some answers, and/or accepting one answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Your application is showing a grid instead of map, which clearly states that your MAP-API key is not proper. I suggest you to re-generate your MAP-API key. Also when you are using this kind of API you nee d to make sure that you can not directly run application from the eclipse. You must create an .apk file of your project and then install it, Then only it will show the Google MAP.

Answer (score 2):

Replace your code :

```
<RelativeLayout
android:id="@+id/resourceMapLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
    android:id="@+id/resourceScreenMapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

by this one:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/resourceMapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment 
        android:id="@+id/resourceScreenMapView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"        
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

If this not solve the problem , then can you please post full code?

Comment: Actually I need to add mapview in fragment so i cant use your code it gives me some error..

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to refer to the MapView directly. The Google Play Services comes with a fragment that will handle various life-cycle events for you automatically.

replace your layout with:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/resourceMapLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/resourceScreenMapView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

than in your code:

```
final GoogleMap map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
    .findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

// This gets the button
map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
map.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);
```

1 last thing regarding API keys. You can test using your debug key (the one eclipse uses when you run using eclipse) under Windows it's located at `C:\Users\USER_NAME\.android\debug.keystore`. You will need to register for a key online using the signature from the debug keystore and add that to your manifest file.